# FunctionComponent typescript error on build

Tags: typescript, next.js

I create a modal on NextJs typescript using FunctionComponent and this error is return on build

> Type error: Type '({ isShown, hide, modalContent, headerText, }:
> ModalProps) => ReactPortal | null' is not assignable to type
> 'FunctionComponent'.   Type 'ReactPortal | null' is not
> assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
> Type 'ReactPortal' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'.
> Types of property 'key' are incompatible.
> Type 'import("C:/Users/f4m75/Documents/diapen project/Wiza/wiza_front/node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").Key
> | null' is not assignable to type 'React.Key | null'.
> Type 'bigint' is not assignable to type 'Key | null'.

Here is my code :

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useEffect } from "react";
import FocusLock from "react-focus-lock";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import {
  Wrapper,
  Header,
  StyledModal,
  HeaderText,
  CloseButton,
  Content,
  Backdrop,
} from "./modal.style";

export interface ModalProps {
  isShown: boolean;
  hide: () => void;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  modalContent: JSX.Element;
  headerText: string;
}

export const Modal: FunctionComponent<ModalProps> = ({
  isShown,
  hide,
  modalContent,
  headerText,
}) => {
  const onKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 27 && isShown) {
      hide();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    isShown
      ? (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden")
      : (document.body.style.overflow = "unset");
    document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
    };
  }, [isShown]);

  const modal = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Backdrop onClick={hide} />
      <FocusLock>
        <Wrapper
          aria-modal
          aria-labelledby={headerText}
          tabIndex={-1}
          role="dialog"
        >
          <StyledModal>
            <Header>
              <HeaderText>{headerText}</HeaderText>
              <CloseButton onClick={hide}>X</CloseButton>
            </Header>
            <Content>{modalContent}</Content>
          </StyledModal>
        </Wrapper>
      </FocusLock>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  // **Pass the document.body element as the second argument to the ReactDOM.createPortal() function**
  return isShown ? ReactDOM.createPortal(modal, document.body) : null;
};
```